# Does Play Framework 2.3 work on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, playframework-2.3

I try to deploy a Play Framework 2.3.0 app to Heroku as described on http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ProductionHeroku.

My simple app runs locally without any problems and pushing/deploying to Heroku does not show any signs of errors.

End of push log:

```
[…]
-----> Building runtime environment
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> (none)

done, 11.0MB
done, v4
       http://xxxxxxxxxxx.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku

To git@heroku.com:xxxxxxxxxxx.git
   f1c57d6..6bb0df3  master -> master
updating local tracking ref 'refs/remotes/heroku/master'
```

When I open the web page I get Heroku's "Application Error" page (not an error page of Play).

If I run `heroku ps` no processes are listed (just nothing).

It's my first Heroku deployment ever. I somehow feel Heroku does not not know how to start the Play app due to the change from the `play` command to `activator` since 2.3.

One more thing: I noticed, on the Heroku Dashboard > App > Settings > Info it says "Framework: Node.js", which is a bit weird, although I do use Bower in the project.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

**UPDATE:** The actual problem is that Heroku thinks my app is a Node.js app and nothing gets compiled as long as I've got a `package.json` file in my repository. As soon as I remove it and commit all dependencies (`bower_components` directory) to the repository everything is fine. I'll have to find a way now to run a Bower update and compile the Play Framework on push...

Comment: You can set the play framework build pack specifically with `heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-scala.git` , and then you should be able to restore your package.json file

Answer (score 0):

Do the logs provide any helpful information? Run `heroku logs -t -a <app_name>` to watch the logs as you deploy or start up your application. Do you have a Procfile defined?

Some handy documentation links:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#realtime-tail
- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile
- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/play-support

Comment: It seems no process is running. Everything seems fine ("`Slug compilation finished`" etc.), but then in the log: `2014-06-19T13:48:35.803786+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=.......`

Comment: That message suggest you do not have a Procfile at all, maybe a Procfile with no web specified, or you simply haven't spun up a web dyno: `$ heroku ps:scale web=1 -a <app_name>`

Comment: I must have missed that indeed as this is described under "Connecting to a database" in the documentation. I have now created a `Procfile` with the following content: `web: target/universal/stage/bin/FILENAME -Dhttp.port=${PORT}`, but the log says `bash: target/universal/stage/bin/FILENAME: No such file or directory`. When I run `play clean stage` locally I get a `target/universal/stage/bin/FILENAME` which is exactly named as in my Procfile. Should I be able to find this file when I log in (`heroku run bash`)? Because there is no `target` directory at all.

Comment: `FILENAME` should be the folder name of your git repo, lowercased. I believe `heroku run bash` uses a one-off dyno (and not your web dyno).

Answer (score 0):

Use [heroku-buildpack-multi](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi).

The contents of your .buildpacks file should look like:

```
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-scala
```